# Identifying frame type from h264 bitstream over RTP

Tags: h.264, rtp

I need to identify each frame type within a h264 bitstream over RTP. So far, I've been able to identify basically everything that wireshark can detect from the bitstream, including:

- Sequence parameter set
- NAL and Fragmentation unit headers, including the nal_ref_idc, and nal type
- NAL Unit payload, including the slice_type bit.

From what I understand, nal_ref_idc can be combined with the slice_type bit to identify the slice_type - that is, I, P or B. But I'm struggling to understand how that is identified.

Finally, I'm not sure how to identify the type of the frame from this. At first I thought that the slices were the same as frames, but that isn't the case. How can I tell, or estimate which slices belong to the same frame, and then identify the frame type?

Thanks!